# Events not triggering anymore in parent ViewController when dismissing a child ViewController

Tags: xcode, events, viewdidappear, ios12

I have a custom UIView built using several UIButtons. In the **viewDidAppear** function of a ViewController I take the subviews of this UIView and attach an addTarget to them. Everything works as expected and the embedded UIButtons acts according to the tap events added, selecting and de-selecting the buttons.

But when I instantiate a new ViewController, show it and then it is dismissed, when I'm back to the parent ViewController, the added events are not responding anymore. The rest of the elements of the parent ViewController work (UITableView, other buttons, etc...). This only happens in **iOS 12**, both simulator and iPhone. In iOS 10 - 11 works like a charm.

What I've seen is that, in IOS 12, when I dismiss the viewController and I'm back to the caller ViewController, no viewDidAppear is being called.

I've lost a couple of day looking for a solution but nothing seems to work. The UIButtons inside my custom UIView class, are responding because I placed some "print()" inside their native tap events, and I get a response when tapping, something must be wrong when I define the addTarget in the ViewController.

Lately I added a UIButton that triggers the function which attachs the event. If I tap on it, the buttons become responsive again. If I call the function as a callback of the Dissmiss method in the Second ViewController... doesn't work. It's like the ViewController wasn't active when I'm back to it.

Must say that the viewControllers are placed inside a Navigation Controller which is inside a Tab Bar Controller.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Disabling "Clear Graphics Context” made the trick**... I don't know why, but I suppose it's the XCode Magic that nobody understand.